# Streams and obtaining and printing out a value from a custom class

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream

I have a custom class just 4 items one being of a Date type. The class is called Latest

type1 refers to the datetime as a Date format. I take the string type and convert it into a Date format first.

I try to get only those entries after 2018-09-30 18:57 and then try and print them. There are 4 items in the class ideally i want to print out all 4 items that make up each item in a class. Can someone assist?

```
final String type1 = "2018-09-30 18:57";
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
Date date = dt.parse(type1);


Stream<List<Date>> workRequestFileTransAuditListforSubmission = attributes.stream()
.filter(file -> file.getAcceptanceTime() > date)
.map(Latest::getAcceptanceTime)
.collect(Collectors.toList());


workRequestFileTransAuditListforSubmission.forEach(System.out::println);`
```

Comment: `file.getAcceptanceTime().after(date)` should be used as condition. `>` can't be used with `Date` objects. Also, you can call `.forEach(System.out::println)` on the stream directly, no need to `collect`.

Comment: @ernest_k thanks for your help i have added .after(date) thank you. im not quite clear how to implement .forEach

Comment: I mean that it can end like this: `...map(Latest::getAcceptanceTime).forEach(System.out::println);` (without the intermediate variable and `collect()` call). You may need to use `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach` if order matters.

Comment: @ernest_k I did try that and i get this error incompatible types: void cannot be converted to Stream<List<Date>> I figured i must be doing something wrong in Java8

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't need to assign that to a variable (If the objective is just to print each value)

Comment: Nope dont need to assign

Comment: When you are going to do `.map(Latest::getAcceptanceTime)` anyway, don’t do double work in the `filter`. Do `map` first, then you don’t need to call `getAcceptanceTime` again in the filter: `attributes.stream() .map(Latest::getAcceptanceTime) .filter(date::isBefore) .forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `after()` or `before()` method to compare two date. And you dont need to use `map` and `collect` to `print` dates.

```
attributes.stream()
        .filter(file -> file.getAcceptanceTime().after(date))
        .forEachOrdered(file -> System.out.println(file.getAcceptanceTime()));
```